# JavaScript: Analyzing someone's site: where does this tag come from?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

i'm currently working on a GreaseMonkey plugin for a news-site and they have a `<script>` tag in there, where rating data for comments is stored and then used to display it along the posts.
I'm AJAX-loading several comment-pages and for some reason this `<script>` tag doesn't show up in my background-loaded pages. What is the best way to analyze where and how this tag is created?

Too broad of a question? :)
Regards

Comment: You could mean just about anything by tag.  Show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download their source HTML with `curl` and see if the `<script>` tag is present in the HTML as initially sent by their server. If not, most likely they are using javascript to add the tag to the DOM after the page is loaded.  You'll have to look through their code to find if that is happening.  Look for event handlers for the document ready event.